# JQuery if statement append data to corresponding DIV based on containing specific string in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I submit a form, depending on the text in the data, I want JQuery to append the data to the correct DIV. I have a series of validation checks on the blah.php page. If validation fails, a message is returned. If validation is successful, text containing 'img src' (i.e. ) is returned.

So if the text returned in 'data' contains 'img src' I want the data to be appended to the blahupdate div. If 'data' does not contain 'img src' in its text I want the data to be appended to the blaherror div.

Below is the code that I have so far

```
<form id="blahform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="blah.php">
<input type="file" name="blahfile" />
<button id="blahbutton">Upload</button>
</form>

<div id="blaherror"></div>

<div id="blahupdate"></div>

$('#blahbutton').click(function(){
    $('#blaherror').empty();

    $('#blahform').ajaxForm(function(data, textStatus){

        if ($('data:contains("img src")')){
            $('#blahupdate').append(data);
        }else{
            $('#blaherror').append(data);
        }

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this the `data` is a string, but I think the following should work:

```
if (data.indexOf('img src') > -1){
    $('#blahupdate').append(data);
}
else {
    $('#blaherror').append(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is just a string (not a JSON object), test against it using regular expressions:

```
$('#blahform').ajaxForm(function(data, textStatus){
    if (/img src/.test(data)){
        $('#blahupdate').append(data);
    }else{
        $('#blaherror').append(data);
    }
});
```